# Azure Bicep - Microsoft.Web/certificates server farm id always empty

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm experiencing incorrect behaviour with linking/importing a `Azure Key Vault` certificate to a `Azure App Service Plan` / `App Service` through `bicep`.

I provide the `serverFarmId` property with my `App Service Plan Id`

```
resource appServiceCertificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2022-03-01' = {
  name: '${keyVaultName}-${keyVaultCertificateName}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: keyVault.id
    keyVaultSecretName: keyVaultCertificateName
    serverFarmId: appServicePlanId // <<<< this is empty somehow
  }
}
```

Azure claims the deployment went 'Ok' for 'Microsoft.Web/certificates'
[image]

But my server farm id always ends up being empty. So the certificate is not available later on
[image]

Although the first step succeeds. There's no certificate linked to my app service.
[image]

The second step (adding the `hostNameBindings`) then fails because the certificate is not found.

```
Cannot find Certificate with name XXX.
```

I've tried multiple ways to get the app service plan id. Which all return a correct and identical result. But when Azure deploys the template, the server farm id becomes empty.

I'm doing a similar approach as in the [Microsoft sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/web-app-certificate-from-key-vault) and multiple online articles. So I'm quite sure, there's something wrong on my end. But I cannot figure out what.

Full module:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param appServiceName string
param appServicePlanName string
param dnsCertificateThumbPrint string
param dnsName string
param keyVaultName string
param keyVaultCertificateName string

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' existing = {
  name: appServiceName
}

/*module appServicePlan 'AppServicePlan.bicep' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  params: {
    appPlanName: appServicePlanName
  }
}*/

//Attempt #1 var appServicePlanId = appService.properties.serverFarmId 
//Attempt #2 var appServicePlanId = appServicePlan.outputs.aspId
var appServicePlanId = resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', appServicePlanName)

resource appServiceCertificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2022-03-01' = {
  name: '${keyVaultName}-${keyVaultCertificateName}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: keyVault.id
    keyVaultSecretName: keyVaultCertificateName
    serverFarmId: appServicePlanId
  }
}

resource mainBinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2022-03-01' = {
  name: dnsName
  parent: appService
  properties: {
    siteName: dnsName
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: dnsCertificateThumbPrint
  }
  dependsOn: [
    appServiceCertificate
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried with the api-version: `2019-08-01`? In the link you provided this version is used

Comment: Akso, in the link provided, it is `hostNameSslStates` not `hostNameBindings` ?

Comment: Do you have the full error message ?

Comment: yeah, switching back a couple of versions seemed to do the trick. @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned, the solution was to revert to version '2019-08-01'